# Auto Branching in svn using teamcity

Tags: svn, teamcity, publishing, webdeploy

I wonder whether it is possible to do auto branching using Teamcity. As currently I am automatically publishing web applications using web deploy and the only thing left is branching as we usually take a branch in svn and then publish the next version. Can any one please advise if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: Not clear!!! You branch for the next version? What do you mean? Do you mean you keep a baseline of your released version as a branch?

Comment: yes. Whenever we do a new publish we take a backup of all as a new svn branch with a version no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open TeamCity Version Control Settings for your release build.

Set "VCS labeling mode" to "Successful only" and specify an appropriate labeling pattern. E.g. `release-build-%system.build.number%`. At the top of this page, enter the checkout rule `+:/trunk => .` then click edit to open the VCS root settings page.

Ensure URL points to the root level of the source control tree E.g. `https://vcserver/` instead of the trunk `https://vcserver/trunk`. Also on this page, set the labeling rule to `trunk=>branches`

Each time you run this build, it will be branched automatically using a new system build number.