# Labelling and branching with continuous integration

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, teamcity-9.0

I have seen the following questions [Auto Branching in svn using teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567589/auto-branching-in-svn-using-teamcity), [TeamCity push feature branches to master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896467/teamcity-push-feature-branches-to-master-branch), [Can TeamCity branches concept be applied to Subversion with Build Chains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718293/can-teamcity-branches-concept-be-applied-to-subversion-with-build-chains) and none of them seem to answer my question.

I have a svn structure like below

> - SVN
>
>   - Framework
>
>     - Visual Studio Solutions that produce dlls. Runs on checkin
>   - Plugins
>
>     - Visual Studio Solutions that produce dlls that depend on the Framework outputs.Runs on checkin
>   - Libraries
>
>     - Visual Studio Solutions that produce dlls that are used by the framework and plugins. Runs on checkin
>   - Products
>
>     - Visual Studio Solutions that **assemble** a number of plugins and framework dlls. Runs nightly

The question is I want to be able to label (tag) all the source that went to creating a particular product build. This means a means of identifying all the plugin,framework and library labels and possibly storing them in some manner so we can recreate the product build if required.

For example, I have two plugins A & B that generate dlls that are stored in some nuget repo. These two dlls are put together into the same output folder by a product build every night. Each night before the product build runs I want to basically take a snapshot of the repository so I can go back to the source that generated the nugets that are contained within the product build.

This cant be done manually because there are 124 plugins, 6 libraries and 5 framework libraries that contribute to a product build each night.

The idea would be to only store it for a month after deployment so as not to use up lots of space. How would I accomplish this with SVN and TeamCity?

Comment: What is your question? You have not heard anything about the tags? I can't see *any* problem here - tag every deploy, tags are cheap in terms of time and space

Comment: @LazyBadger ,thanks for reading. I have added some more clarification. I do understand how tags work, what I am trying or hoping to do is to automate the labeling of the tags and finding a way to group them automatically so I can recreate a product build. Hope thats clearer?

Comment: Well, when you tag, you **label**. And because tag (in SVN) is just subtree in repo, you can copy into tag-root all nodes, which form a final Product (AFAICR, `svn copy` can be even cross-repo operation)

Comment: @LazyBadger, thanks for that, I am asking if there is a way to automate the process with teamcity and or an svn script etc?